# Android Alarm Manager and Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm developing an Android app that has multiple activities, namely Login, Status, Activities, Assignment, ActivityHistory and Planning. The application is supposed to record the user's longitude and latitude every 30 seconds and every 4 minutes it will send the recorded locations to the server. How am I able to register the `BroadcastReceiver` if I have no permanently running activity? Let's say I register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the Status activity and the user clicks on a button and navigates to the Activities activity. Then the Status activity is destroyed and when the user navigates back to the Status, does the `BroadcastReciver` gets registered again?

Comment: When you start a second activity, the first activity is not destroyed, is only stopped.

Comment: You can also declare the receiver in your manifest so that it is attached to your entire application, not any specific activity

Comment: But the receiver method is located in the status activity. And it its stopped does the method still run on the when it fires?

Comment: You should use a Service.

Comment: No I can't.I need this to run even when the phone is asleep.